# Loop through series of Array with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wish to loop through the objects and get the value of the inner array (i.e. region or provider). However this value is a variable and unknown. See example below;

```
[{
    "region": [{
        "name": "EMEA"
    }, {
        "name": "US"
    }]
}, {
    "provider": [{
        "name": "provderOne"
    }, {
        "name": "providerTwo"
    }]
}]
```

How can I get the value of "region"/"provider" (or what ever it might be) and then loop through the inner array to gain access to the object using ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution, it looks messy but it is doable:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <div ng-repeat="(k, lst) in x">
        {{k}}
        <div ng-repeat="y in lst">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in y">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{key}}: {{value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        "region": [{
            "name": "EMEA"
        }, {
            "name": "US"
        }]
    }, {
        "provider": [{
            "name": "provderOne"
        }, {
            "name": "providerTwo"
        }]
    }];
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ue1fcw7q/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
<script>
 var arr = [{
    "region":[
        {"name":"EMEA"},
        {"name":"US"}
    ]
},
{
    "provider":[
        {"name":"provderOne"},
        {"name":"providerTwo"}
    ]
}];

 for(i in arr){
        var val = arr[i];
        for(j in val){
            var sub_key = j;
            console.log(sub_key);
            for(k in val[j]){
         var val1 = val[j][k];
         for(m in val1){
            console.log(val1[m]);

        }

    }
        }
 }

 </script>
```